# Triggering the chrome built in translation feature using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My webpage is contains mixture of English and France.

```
option = Options()
prefs = {
    "translate_whitelists": {
        "es": "en",
        "ru": "en",
        "id": "en",
        "pt": "en",
        "ko": "en",
        "fr": "en",
        "ar": "en",
        "it": "en",
        "nl": "en",
        "th": "en",
        "tr": "en",
        "vi": "en",
        "he": "en",
        "ja": "en",
        "pl": "en", 
        "de": "en"
    },
    "translate": {"enabled": "True"},
}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
option.add_argument("--lang=en")
```

However using code above to initial the chrome and the chrome is detect as english and not translating text that not in English.

I tried to automate with action chain (Shift + F10 + T) to select translate to English from the context menu but it is not working.

Is there any way to trigger chrome built in translation feature using Selenium

Any help will be appreciated.

I wish to always translate the page to English regardless what language is show and mixture.